# Slick in lwjgl doesn't display any text, instead it shows a rectangle

Tags: opengl, text, lwjgl

I am using lwjgl in java and install slick to be able to display text in screen. This is my code:

```
//------------
TrueTypeFont font1;
Font awtFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 24);
font1 = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont, false);
font1.drawString(0, 0, " my text to be displayed ", org.newdawn.slick.Color.blue);
//--------------
```

I wrote this piece of code in update method of my code since I am trying to produce animation but when I run the code it only shows a blue rectangle starting from (0,0) toward top and right side of the screen, it doesnt show the text.

Can anyone help me fix this issue?

Comment: I believe I saw a similar issue a few months ago and the solution was to call `glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D)` before `drawString (...)`. Which is funny because if you look at the implementation of lwjgl it is supposed to do that itself. But you might want to try it nevertheless.

Comment: I add glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D) but there is still problem :(